# How can i make my Semantic Ui menu collapsable

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my Semantic Ui menu, stackable for mobile devices. On low resolutions (mobile devices) i wanna make this collapsable. Insert something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qHuc.png

How can i do this? Ty

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css"
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container" class="ui fluid container">

    <div id="navbar" class="ui stackable yellow inverted menu">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png">
      </div>
      <a class="item" href="">Page1</a>

      <div class="ui pointing dropdown link item">

        <span class="text yellow inverted">Page 2</span>
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>

        <div class="menu">
          <a class="item" href="">Small</a>
          <a class="item">Medium</a>
          <a class="item">Large</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="item" href="">Page 3</a>
      <a class="item" href="">Page 4</a>
      <a class="item" href="">Page 5</a>
    </div>

  </div>



   <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.dropdown').dropdown({
      transition: 'drop',
      on: 'hover'
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put all items to `<div id="hiddable">` and add css mediaquery:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){

       #hiddable { display:none }

}
```

And add

```
$( ".dropdown" ).click(function() {
  $("#hiddable").show();
});
```

or somehting like this.

Comment: i dont want to hide the navbar. i want to make this collapsable